# Why is does web pack bundle-size increase with imports?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I'm using **webpack** to bundle and deploy yet very simple JS functions to a cloud server. I thought of splitting them up into separate files rather than having them all in a single `index.js`.

My project structure basically looks like this:

```
src/
 index.js
 lib/
   func.js
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { 
      'os': false ,
      'path': false,
      'fs': false
    }
  },
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  target: 'webworker',
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
};
```

The file `func.js` is:

```js
export async function createUser({ args, graphql }) {
  const { user } = args;
  return { message: 'hello world!' };
}
```

Now I have bundled two versions of my `index.js`, at first I had the function **directly included** within the index.js:

```js
// index.js including createUser()

async function createUser({ args, graphql }) {
  const { user } = args;
  return { message: 'hello' };
}

// add resolver to schema
self.addGraphQLResolvers({
  "Mutation.createUser": createUser
});
```

which creates the bundle `main.js`

```js
self.addGraphQLResolvers({"Mutation.createUser":async function({args:e,graphql:s}){const{user:r}=e;return{message:"hello"}}});
```

For the **second attempt** I had the function imported from the file `func.js`:

```js
// index.js importing createUser()

const { createUser } = require('./lib/func.js');

// add resolver to schema
self.addGraphQLResolvers({
  "Mutation.createUser": createUser
});
```

which generates

```js
(()=>{var e={248:(e,r,t)=>{"use strict";async function o({args:e,graphql:r}){const{user:t}=e;return{message:"hello"}}t.r(r),t.d(r,{createUser:()=>o})}},r={};function t(o){var a=r[o];if(void 0!==a)return a.exports;var n=r[o]={exports:{}};return e[o](n,n.exports,t),n.exports}t.d=(e,r)=>{for(var o in r)t.o(r,o)&&!t.o(e,o)&&Object.defineProperty(e,o,{enumerable:!0,get:r[o]})},t.o=(e,r)=>Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r),t.r=e=>{"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},(()=>{const{createUser:e}=t(248);self.addGraphQLResolvers({"Mutation.createUser":e})})()})();
```

Both of them work but why is webpack doing this? Do I have a misconfiguration somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like the normal webpack/babel transpilation of client-side JS. A `require` doesn't just source-include the required file, it (roughly speaking) handles modules, import/export, etc.

Comment: Maybe you can try using ES6 modules and then instead of `require` - use `import` ?